# Populate jquery select box and update dropdown

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to populate the options for a select box.

```
function generateTerms(x){
    var optList = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,0);
    $.each(optList, function(i, value) {
        if(value==0){var text='Continuous';}
        else if(value==1){var text=x;}
        else{var text=x+'s';}
        $('#term').append($('<option>', { 'value': value, 'text' : text }));        
    });
    $("#term").trigger("liszt:updated");
}
```

Use of this would be `generateTerms('Year');`

My issue is that it updates the select box generates correctly if you watch the code but it does not update the jquery display system. I thought `.trigger("liszt:updated");`would do it but for some reason it will not.  Im looking for the correct function to run.

Comment: what is the "jquery display system" and what is `"liszt:updated"` ?

Comment: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: ah, in the future, mention that you are using chosen, or any plugin. Otherwise your question is pretty much unanswerable

Answer (score 0):

`liszt:updated` is a custom event, and triggering / binding to it is pretty straightforward. Here's a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/8BhAV/

```
var $term = $('#term'),
    $log = $('#log'),
    $button = $('button');

$term.on('liszt:updated', function (event) {
    $log.html($log.html() + 'Updated at ' + (+new Date()) + '<br>');
});

$button.on('click', function (event) {
    $term.append($('<option>', {
        value: (+new Date()),
        text: (+new Date())
    }));
    $term.trigger('liszt:updated');
});
```

My guess is that you don't have something bound (`$('#term').on('liszt:updated')`) to the custom event you're using.